# Problem with loop on IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i have this javascript function

```
function test(){
            var count = 0;
            var date1 = $('#alternatestartdate').val();
            var date2 = $('#alternateenddate').val();                
            var startDate = new Date(date1);
            var endDate = new Date(date2);

            var loop = true;
            while (loop)
            {
            $('#pa').append('first test');                
            if (startDate<=endDate)
            {
            $('#pa').append('second test');
            loop = true;                
            }
            startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate()+1);
            }
            else
            {
            loop = false;
            }                
            }                
        }
```

The problem is the function will not enter the if loop when tested in IE8. So only **first test** will be printed. **second test** will not be printed. Other browser all work fine. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be that IE is not taking the date format that you are getting from your inputs -since your code works correctly on other browsers-.

To avoid that, I would recommend you to parse the date string, to extract the numerical parts of it, and use the [`Date` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/global_objects/date).

The `Date` constructor can take the following arguments

```
new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, ms);
```

The being the `day`, `hours`, `minutes`, `seconds` and `ms` optional.

But you should remember to substract `1` from the month number, because they are 0-based (0=Jan, 2=Feb, ... 11=Dec).

Of you could use a function like [this one](http://gist.github.com/422052) that I've made some time ago, which does all the job, and you can specify a format to parse your date, e.g.:

```
var date = parseDate('09-26-2010', 'mm-dd-yyyy');
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your code structure...It seems that your else is hanging without an if.

function test()
      {
        var count = 0;
        var date1 = $('#alternatestartdate').val();
        var date2 = $('#alternateenddate').val();
        var startDate = new Date(date1);
        var endDate = new Date(date2);

```
    var loop = true;
    while (loop)
    {
      $('#pa').append('first test');                
      if (startDate<=endDate)
      {
        $('#pa').append('second test');
        loop = true;                
      }
      startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate()+1);
    }
    else
    {
      loop = false;
    }                
  }                
}
```

Comment: the actual structure is correct. sorry it seems i make mistake while simplify the code to ask in this forum.

Comment: np, we all do it from time to time :)